# Change method implementation in Android with Byte Buddy

Tags: java, android, bytecode, byte-buddy

I want to have the implementation of some methods of Android SDK's [Resources](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources) class, such as [getString()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources#getString(int)) use my own implementation.

I can't create my own overridden/proxy version of `Resources` as I get the instance from [Context#getResources](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getResources()). I think that I need to have what `Byte Buddy` calls as "type rebasing" in its [tutorial](https://bytebuddy.net/#/tutorial).

Is this possible in Android? If yes, am I supposed to use the [Byte Buddy Gradle plugin for Android](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/blob/master/byte-buddy-gradle-plugin/android-plugin/README.md) to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot instrument classes within Android's core libraries. You can only instrument your own classes that call into Android by using `MemberSubstitution`.